Is my calculation on chain rule of matrix calculus correct?
My objective function is $h(W)=f(g(\widetilde W))$. The $W$ is a big matrix, which has the size $Kp \times Kp$. The matrix $\widetilde W$ is a small matrix, which has the size $p \times p$. Each element of $\widetilde W$ is the Frobenius norm squared of each $K \times K$ block of $W$.
I don't need to consider technical details. So we can safely assume that both $f$ and $g$ are differentiable. Now I need to compute the gradient of $h(W)$ with respect to $W$.
I currently know the answer of $\nabla_{\widetilde{W}} h(\widetilde{W})$. I need to use chain rule and the previous established result. But I am not sure whether my chain rule formula will be correct.
$$\nabla_W h(W) = \nabla_{\widetilde{W}} f(g(\widetilde{W})) \cdot \nabla_W \widetilde{W}$$
The first factor is $\nabla_{\widetilde{W}} f(g(\widetilde{W})) = \nabla_{\widetilde{W}} h(\widetilde{W})$. The $\cdot$ is the usual matrix multiplication.
Question: is my above the calculation correct?

I think you are missing the partial wrt $g$:
$$\frac{\partial h(\mathbf W)}{\partial\mathbf W}=\frac{\partial f(g(\tilde{\mathbf W}))}{\partial g(\tilde{\mathbf W})}\frac{\partial g(\tilde{\mathbf W})}{\partial \tilde{\mathbf W}}\frac{\partial \tilde{\mathbf W}}{\partial \mathbf W}$$

@JoanS.GuillametF. your expression contains 3 factors. But I think the combination of your first and second factor is just my $\nabla_{\widetilde{W}} f(g(\widetilde{W}))$.

I see, then it is correct.

@JoanS.GuillametF. Great, thank you!

You have written an equation where  a function of a $Kp \times Kp$ matrix is equal to a function of a $p \times p$ matrix. How is this possible?

@TedBlack Maybe a more precise way is to say $h(W)=f(g(z(W)))$, where $z(W)=\widetilde{W}$

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\k{\otimes}
\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\E{{\cal E}}
\def\Eij{\E_{ij}}
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\Si{\sum_{i=\o}^p}
\def\Sj{\sum_{j=\o}^p}
\def\Sk{\sum_{k=\o}^p}
\def\Wij{W_{ij}}
\def\Gij{G_{ij}}
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\I{I}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Let's write $W$ explicitly as a block partitioned matrix
$$\eqalign{
W &= \Si\Sj\: E_i\,\Wij\,E_j^T
 \;=\; \m{
W_{\o\o}&W_{\o 2}&\ldots&W_{\o p} \\
W_{2\o}&W_{22}&\ldots&W_{2p} \\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\
W_{p\o}&W_{p2}&\ldots&W_{pp} \\
}
\\
E_j &= \e_j\k\I,\quad \Eij=\e_i\e_j^T \\
\e_j &\in \R{p},\qquad\;\:\Eij\in\R{p\times p}, \qquad\I,\Wij\in\R{K\times K}, \quad E_j\in\R{Kp\times K}, \quad W\in\R{Kp\times Kp} \\
\Wij &= E_i^TWE_j \quad\qiq\quad d\Wij = E_i^T\,dW\,E_j \\
}$$
For ease of typing, I will use $X=\widetilde W\in\R{p\times p}\,$ which can be written as
$$\eqalign{
X &= \Si\Sj\: \Eij\,\frob{\Wij}^2
 \qiq dX = \Si\Sj\: \Eij\,\LR{2\Wij:d\Wij} \\
}$$
You have a function for which you already know the gradient wrt $X.\:$
Let's call that gradient $G$ and expand it in terms of the standard basis vectors $\LR{\e_i\,\e_j^T}$
$$
G=\grad hX=\Si\Sj\:\Eij\,\Gij\qiq\Gij=G:\Eij\qquad\qquad\qquad
$$
Then you wanted to calculate the gradient wrt $W$, so lets's do that
$$\eqalign{
dh
 &= G:dX \\
 &= G:\Si\Sj\: \Eij\,\LR{2\Wij:d\Wij} \\
 &= 2\Si\Sj\: \Gij\LR{\Wij:d\Wij} \\
 &= 2\Si\Sj\: \Gij\LR{\Wij:E_i^T\,dW\,E_j} \\
 &= 2\Si\Sj\: \Gij\LR{E_i\Wij E_j^T:dW} \\
\grad hW
 &= 2\Si\Sj\: \Gij\LR{E_i\Wij E_j^T}
 \;=\; 2\m{
G_{\o\o}W_{\o\o}&G_{\o 2}W_{\o 2}&\ldots&G_{\o p}W_{\o p} \\
G_{2\o}W_{2\o}&G_{22}W_{22}&\ldots&G_{2p}W_{2p} \\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\
G_{p\o}W_{p\o}&G_{p2}W_{p2}&\ldots&G_{pp}W_{pp} \\
}
}$$
The $\Gij$ are scalar components of $G$, but the other indexed symbols are all matrices.
Also note that a colon represents the Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
A:B = \trace{A^TB} \;=\; B:A \:=\: B^T:A^T = etc \\
}$$
and $\k$ represents the Kronecker product.
Update
Here's an alternate way to write the partitioning
that might be easier to visualize
$$\eqalign{
W = \Si\Sj\:\Eij\k\Wij \\
}$$
Picking up the differentiation at the third line
$$\eqalign{
dh &= 2\Si\Sj\: \Gij\,\Wij:d\Wij \\
 &= 2\Si\Sj\:\LR{\Eij\k\Gij\Wij}:dW \\
\grad hW
 &= 2\Si\Sj\:\Eij\k\LR{\Gij\,\Wij} \\
}$$
Using the Hadamard product $\odot$ and the all-ones matrix $\,J\in\R{K\times K}$
$$\eqalign{
\grad hW &= 2\LR{G\k J}\odot W \qquad\qquad\qquad
}$$

I don't understand that $d X=\sum_{i=1}^p \sum_{j=1}^p \mathcal{E}{i j}\left(2 W{i j}: d W_{i j}\right)$. I know $\frac{\partial||\mathbf X||^2_F}{\partial \mathbf X}=2\mathbf X$.

Rearranging your known formula yields $$d|X|^2_F = 2X:dX$$ Now replace the matrix $X$ with the matrix $W_{ij}$

I see. This is my first time to see this colon representation. I guess your colon means the Frobenius inner product?

So I guess $\langle\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B}\rangle_{\mathrm{F}} = A:B$?

Another question is I am looking for a more concise notation to denote the final answer $\frac{\partial h}{\partial W}$. It looks like $G \otimes W $. But it is not correct. Maybe I can denote it by Hadamard product?

A Hadamard expression was appended to the answer.

Nice one, greg. I'm a fan of yours. Reading your answers throughout the years has lead me to appreciate matrix calculus.

@JackozeeHakkiuz I couldn't agree more

One follow-up question. Suppose we have $K=1$, then $J$ is a scalar 1, and every element of $ \widetilde W$ is the absolute value of $W$ (the Frobenius norm of a real number). By the answer we have $\frac{\partial h}{\partial W}=2G \odot W $, where $G=\frac{\partial h}{\partial \widetilde W}$. I want to verify the answer is correct. How to use the established result $\frac{d |X|_F}{dX}=\frac{X}{|X|}$ to verify? I just want to make sure the answer is correct by checking when $K=1$ case.

Remember that each element of $X$ was defined as the Frobenius norm squared so the established result that you'll want use is $$\frac{\partial |A|_F^2}{\partial A} = 2A$$
